# Maximum and minimum of a fractional function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Let $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$, $a, b, c$ are three real parameters with $c\neq 0$. Find the maximum and minimum of
$\dfrac{ax+by+c}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}}$

This is quite complicated if I calculate the derivative. Is there any other ways? Please help me.

Thanks.

**I know that some people have voted my question down, I know how to use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, but this only gives me the maximum, not the minimum. I'm not good at this kind of math, so, instead of voting down, please explain for me.**

Comment: Define $u=(x,y,1)$ and $v=(a,b,c)$. Then you're just looking at $u\cdot v/|u|$...

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz gives you the minimum as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function, call it $F$, is $c$ times the dot product of $(a/c,b/c,1)$ and the unit vector $\vec{n}$ in the direction of $(x,y,1)$. If $\theta$ is the angle between $(a/c,b/c,1)$ and $\vec{n}$, then $(a/c,b/c,1) \cdot \vec{n}$ is minimized when $\cos\theta = -1$, in which case the minimum value of $F$ is $c(-\|(a/c,b/c,1)\|) = -\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}$, if $c > 0$. If $c < 0$, the minimum value of $F$ is $c$ times the maximum of $(a/c,b/c,1) \cdot \vec{n}$. Since $(a/c,b/c,1)\cdot \vec{n}$ is maximized when $\cos\theta = 1$, the minimum of $F$ is $c\|(a/c,b/c,1)\| = -\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}$.

Comment: It's actually not so easy. Since the last component of $\vec{n}$ is positive, the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality gives you only one, the maximum if $c > 0$, and the minimum if $c < 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2+1}+\frac{y^2}{x^2+y^2+1}+\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+1}=1,$$
we know that to find the extremas of $\displaystyle \frac{ax+by+c}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}}$ is equivalent to find the extremas of $g(x,y,z)=ax+by+cz$ over the hemi-sphere $\{(x,y,z):x^2+y^2+z^2=1,z>0\}$.

By the Lagrange Multiplier Method, we set $F(x,y,z,\lambda)=ax+by+cz-\lambda(x^2+y^2+z^2-1)$. Solving equations
$$\left\{
        \begin{aligned}
            \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}&=a-2\lambda x=0,\\
            \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}&=b-2\lambda y=0,\\
            \frac{\partial F}{\partial z}&=c-2\lambda z=0,\\
            \frac{\partial F}{\partial \lambda}&=-(x^2+y^2+z^2-1)=0,
        \end{aligned}\right.$$
yields
$$\left\{
        \begin{aligned}
            x&=\frac{a}{2\lambda},\\
            y&=\frac{b}{2\lambda},\\
            z&=\frac{c}{2\lambda}.
        \end{aligned}\right.\quad\text{and}\quad2\lambda=\pm\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}\neq 0.$$
It is easy to see that there is no extrema point if $c=0$. When $c>0$, we have
$$\left\{
        \begin{aligned}
            x&=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}},\\
            y&=\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}},\\
            z&=\frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}.
        \end{aligned}\right.$$
Consider the Hessian matrix,
$$H_F=\left(\begin{aligned}
            -\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}&& && \\ &&-\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}&& \\ && &&-\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2} 
        \end{aligned}\right),$$
we know that it is negative-definite. Hence, $g(x,y,z)$ has a unique maximal point, i.e.
$$\displaystyle (x,y,z)=\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}},\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}},\frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}\right),$$
hence the maximum of $g(x,y,z)$ is
$$g\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}},\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}},\frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}\right)=\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}.$$
In this situation, $g(x,y,z)$ has no minimum point.

Similarly, when $c<0$, we know the minimum of $g(x,y,z)$ is
$$g\left(-\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}},-\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}},-\frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}\right)=-\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2},$$
and $g(x,y,z)$ has no maximum.